# Cannot Browse to specific Type in Settings designer for WPF/.net Core application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, settings

When I've used Settings Designer before, I've been able to browse to find non-standard Types (e.g. uncommon enums etc) to use in my Settings via a "Browse" button at the bottom of the drop down under the "Type" column. I'm developing a WPF desktop application for .net Core and there is no Browse option as pictured below:

[image]

I did go into the code behind (`Settings.Designer.cs.`) and edit the code manually, but on saving, this just reverted to string. I'm guessing this may have something to do with settings also having an element in App.config and I notice it has a "serialiseAs" tag - didn't know what to put here. Exmaple of the code behind settings and App.config:

```cs
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
public string UiTheme {
    get {
        return ((string)(this["UiTheme"]));
    }
    set {
        this["UiTheme"] = value;
    }
}
```

```xml
<userSettings>
    <GameBoxer.WPF.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="UiTheme" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </GameBoxer.WPF.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Does anyone know how to bring back the 'Browse'?? Or, how to correctly do it in code?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community

Thanks

---

UPDATE: So, I learn that this is "By Design" in VS2022 according to MS [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-Properties-gt;Settingssettings/1690711?entry=problem&ref=native&refTime=1664392226374&refUserId=d4644839-c668-47a8-88c2-f21ed51060fb). It's still present in VS2019! But they've taken it out of VS2022 and I can't figure how to do it in code. MS, you're one of my faves out the bunch, but sometimes, you're as mad as a box of frogs. unfortunately that link doesn't provide the poster with any alternatives other than "that's not a bug." Not very helpful, really.

Comment: In my test, it can be displayed normally in project->properties->settings->general->create, I suggest you enter the installer to repair vs.

Comment: Tried that - didn't work. Can I just check - you're dev environment was WPF .net Core 3.1?

Comment: Yes, I [tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGrW4.png) under [3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A60oO.png). I suggest you [repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUmQy.png) it.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT That repair advice doesn't work.  Even the screenshot you posted shows it doesn't work.  Not sure if you didn't understand the question or what.

Comment: Quite. I just left it as, as per my update, I think it's just left broken by MS at the moment, sadly. Not sure why MSFT are suggesting it's user error 

Comment: In the same test environment it works fine for me. If I can't reproduce the error, I can't repair it. I'm very sorry.

Comment: And as of now the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/settings-page-project-designer?view=vs-2022&source=docs) are still outdated and say it's possible, sadly.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I'm afraid you've vastly misunderstood the issue. In the past we were able to add our own custom defined types to be used to serialize to the settings file. Yes, we can browse the current list of natively supported types - but not add our own.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link you provided, this change was by design due to .NET Core and while I very strongly disagree with their stance on this - I'm assuming this was done because it could be quite fiddly to get your own types to work as expected, especially for new users.

One simple workaround if your custom data has several values, you can use `string` and simply write your own little parser using delimiters such as `;`. You could also use `StringCollection` to achieve the same result.

Inconvenient, yes. But a simple solution nonetheless.

I sincerely hope Microsoft changes their stance on this and looks at reimplementing this as it worked remarkably well once you figured out the procedure to get it to serialize properly.

**Edit:**

Figured I might as well provide an example;

```cs
// Storing the Settings
// Parameter: Struct { Location(Point), Size(Point), Margin(Thickness) }
var settingString = $"{e.Location.X};{e.Location.Y};{e.Size.X};{e.Size.Y};{e.Margin.Left};{e.Margin.Top};{e.Margin.Right};{e.Margin.Bottom}";
Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting = settingString;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

// Parsing the Saved Setting
var settingString = Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settingString))
{
    List<string> splitStrings = settingString.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    List<double> parsedValues = new List<double>();
    splitStrings.ForEach(x => parsedValues.Add(double.Parse(x)));

    var location = new Point(parsedValues[0], parsedValues[1]);
    var size = new Point(parsedValues[2], parsedValues[3]);
    var margin = new Thickness(parsedValues[4], parsedValues[5], parsedValues[6], parsedValues[7]);
}
```

There's probably better ways of doing this, but I find this to be a very simple workaround and has worked great thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You can still edit the settings file manually and add the needed properties with their custom classes. Just don't use the tabular editor afterwards, as it overwrites the changes made manually. As the settings are not that often changed, this should be no big deal.

Here are two examples. The first one uses an enumeration from a class library (referenced in the code as dbIT) I use for most of my projects, the second example uses a complex class.

I am using VB.Net with Visual Studio 2022.

```
    <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),
        Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),
        Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("None")>
    Public Property ServerMode() As Global.dbIT.Enums.ServerMode
        Get
            Return CType(Me("ServerMode"), Global.dbIT.Enums.ServerMode)
        End Get
        Set
            Me("ServerMode") = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),
        Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Public Property LocalLicense() As Global.dbIT.Classes.LocalLicense
        Get
            Return CType(Me("LocalLicense"), Global.dbIT.Classes.LocalLicense)
        End Get
        Set
            Me("LocalLicense") = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Both are being correctly serialized in the user.config file. Reading them back and using them works too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<userSettings>
    <TestApp.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="ServerMode" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Local</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="LocalLicense" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
                <LocalLicense xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <LocalLicenseKey>XYZ-This-is-a-test</LocalLicenseKey>
                    <DemoMode>false</DemoMode>
                    <TrialMode>false</TrialMode>
                    <GraceDate>2024-01-11T15:24:51.7447994+01:00</GraceDate>
                </LocalLicense>
            </value>
        </setting>
    </TestApp.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

It was still a bad decision from Microsoft to remove this feature.